# how to make wordpress pages redirect to a totally different place

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a website , installed in it wordpress blog , there is a menu in the header with pages inside the blog that i made ,,, anyway what if i needed to totally change where the user go when he clicks on that page (menu item) ?? permalink only allow you to edit  the rest of the link not the whole link !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the answer. Appearance=> menus => make new custom menu ... the theme should support custom menus though and in the settings of the theme i found (Check if you would like to use Custom Navigation Menus in WordPress 3.0.)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the function `wp_safe_redirect()` or you simply use some rewrites in your .htaccess with perform much faster as they don't have "to load" wordpress.

Even if the rewrites in the .htaccess would match a permalink you can use them by adding the [L] flag, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule wordpress/pagename$ some_other_page.php [L]
```

The [L] flag (last) will stop apache looking at the outher rules.

Answer (score 0):

On a more generic note (if you don't have a custom menu), what I'd probably do is to create a custom page template for the pages that I want to redirect somewhere else, probably using Wordpress custom fields to specify what URL exactly.

Like Kau-Boy implied above, this is a bit slower because Wordpress has to load --- but if you've got "pages" that have to change regularly, this might be more convenient and familiar than `.htaccess` mods.